# jQuery load local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for my mobile application I want to load HTML code dynamically into a container.

I tried the load method form jQuery but chrome is saying:

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My Code:

```
container.load("feeds.html");
```

I think this should be possible. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you running this code locally on your own machine?

Comment: what if you do something like this `$('#' + container).load('feeds.html');`

Comment: Yes my site should be loaded into a webview from a local folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `load()` from a local source as there is no `origin` header provided. You need to change the logic to load `jsonp` if you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing). either  you need to get values as Jsonp or a small work around from previous answers [Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

use $.getJSON. It does a little magic to change the request type from its default of "json" to "jsonp" if it sees the substring `callback=?` in the URL.